# Playback of widevine custom encrypted content on chromecast

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, video-streaming, drm, widevine

I am testing widevine custom encrypted content on chrome cast.

When I was able to play back same content on shaka player.

But I am getting:

> "Fatal Error: Code 2"

after license response reached to chrome cast; is there any different format for license response for chrome cast?

And I am getting one OPTIONS empty request also what is this exactly?

Comment: There isn't much information about your setup. What receiver are you using?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

Comment: You should try the reference receiver: https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample

Comment: But when i was hosted that file in Drive blank screen i am getting not any info related to receiver.

Comment: The Cast-Player-Sample is a receiver so you should configure your sender to use that receiver and see what happens.

Comment: @AliNaddaf sir, using  github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample receiver
what customData fields should be in my cast sender android app. I'm using licenceUrl which is containing whole url key of widevine content. But I'm not able to play video.